# Portal: The First Slice Demo Glitch

Tags: portal

I thought of trying out the demo of Portal before I bought the game and was amazed.  But then after chamber 10 something weird happened that wouldn't allow me to continue to chamber 11.  I wasn't sure whether this is a glitch or the demo was over.

[image]

The problem is that the exit from the elevator is very warped.  I can shoot portals into the weird warped wall but I can't walk through it.  What is going on?!

Comment: FYI, that type of graphical glitch occurs when there is literally _nothing_ in that direction — the game doesn't bother drawing anything in particular for “nothing”, so you see stuff from previous frames that wasn't drawn over by actual walls. In a properly running game you should never see that, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the files probably got messed up when you were downloading or something. Go to your steam library, right click on the demo and click "properties", then go to the "local files" tab, and then click "verify integrity of game cache" fixes a lot of issues like that for me.

This only works if you're playing via steam though.

If you dont mind losing your progress to that point, you can just uninstall and reinstall and it should work fine.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!  I am running through steam

Comment: Let me know if that fixes it :)

Comment: That didn't fix it sorry. :(

Comment: uninstalling and reinstalling didnt fix either? I'm sorry man... The demo does end after chamber 11 though. I will say this: this summer, the game will be on sale for 5 bucks on steam. That's an amazing deal. Pick it up!

Comment: Really!  That's awesome!  I will be looking forward to that!  Do you know when exactly?

Comment: It's never really set in stone, but portal is always up to 75% off one day and 50% off the rest I'm pretty sure

Comment: Wait you kind of need to fix your grammar there @Zorpix.  What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain more. During the steam sales, everything goes on sale. But every day, they have different daily deals that offer bigger discounts than the normal sale prices. For example, portal is 50% off for the entirety of the sale, but on one or two days of the sale, it will be knocked down to 75% off.

Comment: Oh okay thanks for that!  If you see it on sale one day let me know!

Comment: Not sure how to on here...

Comment: @EthanBaconGaming You can get [The Portal Bundle](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/7932/), which currently costs 6.24. Get it within 41 hours of this comment before the sale expires.

Answer (score -2):

I think you beat the demo. There is 11 chambers in the demo while it starts at chamber 00 so chamber 10 would be the last chamber

Comment: That doesn't look like a victory screen to me.